# Which bike multitool should I get for a cannondale trail 3 2019? Which other tools will I need?

Tags: tools, new-bicycle-assembly, multi-tool

I have just purchased a Cannondale Trail 3 2019 online and the bike will arrive pre-assembled in a box. I am new to bikes and mtb, I have no tools or anything.

I saw online I require a multitool and a pump, but other online tutorials say you should buy the multitool that suits your specific bike.

Which multitool for my Cannondale Trail 3 should I get? Which other tools will I need? Please just the minimal to assemble and give basic service.

Comment: Do you consider yourself "handy" ?  There's little point carrying a tool if you're unable to use it.

Comment: The helmet part is unrelated and can't be answered here anyway - go to your LBS and try them on.  Comfort and Fit is everything, and is unrelated to your height.

Comment: @Criggie carrying tools and spares to suit your bike is always a good idea - a willing stranger can't help you if you don't have the tool, tube or pump for the job.

Comment: Actually, we don't know how much assembly work has been done on the bike already. The good internet sellers like Canyon ship their bikes nearly ready to ride. It doesn't seem likely here, but the bike may have had the rotors and tires installed, maybe derailers adjusted, maybe chain already cut to length. The OP may not need all the tools listed below to get out the door. Unfortunately, he might - we just don't know.

Comment: You can't take anything for granted on a bike that comes in a box. Even if it's almost fully assembled you should check everything from end to end. Spoke tension, brake adjustment, derailleur adjustment,  lube the seat post, lube the pedal threads, etc. Poor assembly will make a good bike frustrating. You need more than a multi-tool.

Comment: If it is an online order, it is highly recommandable to use a **torque** wrench to set-up your stem, handlebars and to a smaller degree also the seat tube clamp. Those are easy to snap. The rexommended torques are usually printed on the parts and are not guge. It is not hard to accidentally overtorque them.

Comment: @WeiwenNg The OP won't need all the tools listed in the answers to get riding. But he will need most of them when somerging breaks or loosens. He is likely to do his first warranty maintanence (~200 km) himself so will need to check that various parts did not become loosened. The chain tool is when the chain snaps on a ride. One does not buy one multitool for set-up and one for riding.

Comment: Pre-assembled would mean "already assembled" and not "prior to being assembled".  If the bike arrives in pieces, it is "unassembled".

Answer (score 9):

I wouldn’t get a multi tool.

All the tools you need for a modern bicycle (if you are not replacing bearings, crankset or cassette) are:

- **4mm hex key** for:

  - seat post clamp
  - stem+handlebars
  - bottle holders
  - racks
- **5mm hex key** for:

  - rim brakes brake lever clamps
  - derailleurs
  - saddle rail clamps
- **T25 torx** for:

  - disc brake rotors
- **8mm hex** key for:

  - pedals
- **screwdriver** for:

  - derailleur limit screws
- spoke key for wheel spokes
- tire levers
- pump
- chain tool

Get a set of proper hex keys and the T25 torx if you have disc brakes. Get tire levers, a small pump for the ride and a large pump for the workshop.

But on single day rides it doesn’t make sense to bring any of keys. You really only need the small pump, tire levers and a spare tube.

When I’m making saddle adjustments I take a 4mm hex key (and maybe a 5mm key if I’m also adjusting the fore-aft position) for the ride.

On multi-day travel I bring the 4mm and 5mm keys plus spare shifter cables and spare bottle holder screws. I also bring the spoke key and spare spokes (only makes sense if you know how to use it). A multi tool would have too many tools on it (which makes it heavier than the two dedicated keys) and they are usually short and fiddly.

If you have disc brakes and need/want a T25 Torx key I’d get [this](https://www.topeak.com/us/en/products/tool-replacement-kit/1119-t25-bit) T25 Torx bit from Topeak which turns a 4mm allen key into a fully functional T25 Torx key.

Comment: Regarding single day rides, it may be that you never notice things out of adjustment, screws working loose or the need to adjust the saddle or handlebars a bit on the road. My experience is different.

Comment: I’ve only ever had bottle holder and rear rack screws coming loose (because the torque on those screws is so tiny) and I’ve solved that problem by using threadlocker. Take a 4mm hex key with you if you are concerned about that.

Comment: Did you have thread locker with you?

Comment: [Individual hex keys](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07BKWNXJX) are also much stronger than those that are fixed to a set/multitool, especially more than those with a plastic handle. They also give more leverage and some feature a ball point, so I'd recommend against multitool-hex-keys.

Comment: It is quite important to note that what your bike is 4 mm vs, 5 mm is really only valid for your bike. It differs between bikes. Sometimes the vendor chooses 4 mm, sometimes 5 mm, I even have 3 mm hex bottle holding bolts on one. Rear wheel thru axles may require a 6 or 8 mm hex key. That is why the OP read that he should get the multitool according to his bike. The bolts used on bikes do differ.

Comment: Of course if you are going to buy single keys you should measure your screw heads before buying.

Comment: 6 mm hex can be needed for saddle fore/aft adjustments, depending on the clamp style

Comment: I'm a former bike mechanic, so I'm used to having a full set of high quality tools in front of me. It's very nice. But since I'm a *former* bike mechanic, I also own a multi-tool because it's super convenient, much cheaper than a full set of tools and 95% of the time, it gets the job done. Also, many small parts on bikes (such as grip clamps) require smaller hex keys than 4mm.

Comment: Forget about the individual hex keys and just get one of the sets from [park](https://www.parktool.com/product/professional-l-shaped-hex-wrench-set-hxs-1-2?category=Hex%20%26%20Torx%C2%AE%20Compatible%20Tools) or [pedros](https://pedros.com/products/tools/general-tool/l-hex-wrench-set/) or similar. If you think you'll do a lot of wrenching splurge on the plastic overmolded ones.

Comment: @whatsisname But these are individual keys too - they just come in a plastic holder, of which they can be taken out of. In a [multitool](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B075RWH8DG/) they are connected such that you can exert much less force, can't take a subset of them with you, and don't have a ball point.

Comment: @Erlkoenig: my comment was more in regards to the idea of selecting a few specific sizes, and the commenters saying whether it's better to use 4 vs 5 or vs 6mm or whatever. Better to buy a pack of all of them, than to buy some number of individual hex keys.

Comment: @Erlkoenig - No dispute individual keys are much stronger, but torques on bicycles (in the sizes that come with multi tools) are much less than you need to worry about too strength. Gorillas with a spanner should not work on modern bicycles, if you are any where near the torque it makes a difference, you are doinf it all wrong.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a great idea to assemble the bike with a multitool. Multitools are short, which means you can't exert as much leverage as with a regular tool; and have a joint between the handle and tool heads, which means they are not as stiff. Multitools are a compromise to allow you to carry them while riding and be able to make adjustments if you need to. If you plan to do adjustments and servicing yourself, buy the proper tools. They will be far easier and effective to use. The list that Michael provided is a great start.

Do you need a multitool to carry with you on a ride? That's personal preference. A spare tube and a mini pump or CO2 inflater are probably more important.

Comment: -1: If you are using so much force that the multitool cannot easily exert the required leverage, you are over torquing every fastener on a modern bicycle.

Comment: @mattnz I'm talking about loosening them as well as doing them up

Comment: @mattnz I definitely bent a multi-tool putting my pedals on. I dispute the "every fastener" claim.

Comment: @mattnz Crank bolts, pedals, suspension bolts, some single-bolt saddle clamps...

Answer (score 5):

Check what type of fasteners you have on your bike. Usually its bolts with allen key heads or torx heads. Most multitools have both but you could choose only allen/torx after you've checked that your bike only has 1 of the 2.

From some brief googling it looks to me like you have (mostly) allen head bolts (six sided).

**here's a comparison of what they look like :**

[image]

A flathead and philips heads screwdriver will also be very useful (for derailleur adjustment for example).

Some multitools come with a built in chain tool, which I find is a must. If you don't get a multitool with this built in you could always take a seperate chain tool but there will be more bulk and weight.

For 20-30 euro you should definitely be able to get a multitool that meets all these requirements, probably you can find it cheaper if you look around a bit.

**Here is the multitool I'm currently using.**
https://www.belgafietsen.nl/specialized-emt-12-minitool.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIt8O-4N7u5wIVUud3Ch2pgAZqEAQYBiABEgLIZfD_BwE
[image]

**a similar alternative:**
https://www.internet-bikes.com/195523-sigma-multitool-pocket-tool-medium-16-functies-zwart/?tt=10107_12_290797&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIt8O-4N7u5wIVUud3Ch2pgAZqEAQYBSABEgIxO_D_BwE

One more thing to check is the length of the multitool itself since when you're using it and you've got one of the tools extended you're using the body of the multitool as leverage so the longer it is the better (in terms of leverage).

Comment: Also check the leverage on the chain tool. I have two similar multitools and on one of them the wing on the chain tool is smaller and it s very hard to breakk the chain. Impossible without good gloves.

Comment: Personally, I like the Lezyne stainless steel multitools.  They don't get all rusty if you ride in wet weather.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience it's difficult at best to find individual hex and torx wrenches. They all seem to come in sets, and when I can find an individual wrench it's usually really expensive compared to just buying a set.

For outfitting a new workbench/shop I'd definitely advise a set of individual wrenches. But for on a bike I prefer a multitool.  Note that no multitool will fit everything as bicycles require a number of unique tools for things like bottom brackets.

My preference is for the Lezyne stainless steel multitools. The Stainless 20 will have everything you'll need for basic fixes. (Hex, Torx, screw drivers, chain tool)

The Crank Brothers M19 is similar in the collection of tools, but it is carbon steel that is harder and less likely to deform (round). But it'll rust and is a bit heavier than the Lezyne. The M19 has Torx T10 & T25 while the Lezyne only has the T25. The chain tool on the M19 is rated for 8 thru 12 speed while the Lezyne is only rated for 8-11 speed.

Your Cannondale dealer should be able to guide you through the complete list of bolt sizes on your new bike. Wheels for example may require a unique spoke wrench. You may be able to get a smaller tool and save a bit of $$$ and weight.

I own both the Lezyne and M19 and they've worked well when needed. Get a good quality tool and it'll never disappoint. Cheap tools generally fail at the worst possible time.

Comment: "Cheap tools generally fail at the worst possible time." such truth!

Comment: @Swifty Sometimes true, sometimes not.  I've gone over a decade with the same $9 Nashbar multi-tool. I don't think they even make them anymore. I bought an M19 to replace it, but I gave the Crank to a friend who didn't have a tool.

Comment: You want individual hex keys, mcmaster-carr can set you up

Answer (score 3):

If the bike has been pre-assembled before shipping, there should be minimal work for you to do in the first instance. This should include turning the handlebars, attaching the pedals, adjusting the saddle and checking the tyres are inflated. You might also adjust the position of the controls (i.e. brake lever angle). These tasks require Allen keys in 4, 5, 6 mm, and either a 8 mm Allen key or 15 mm pedal spanner for the pedals, depending on your design - normally a 15 mm pedal spanner for included (basic) pedals.

So that's it, **Allen keys, pedal spanner and pump**. All of these Allen key sizes will be included on any multitool so you can choose freely, considering other advice and what maintenance you plan or expect to do. Other answers suggesting Torx keys and chain tools etc - these features will be useful at some point in the future and you should buy a quality, long-lasting tool when you do purchase one.

Remember that the left pedal is left hand threaded. Many new bike owners have had to head to the LBS for a repair or replacement of the left crank, reducing that mail order bargain effect. Do ensure the pedals are fixed tightly to the cranks.

You may find that the bike ships with a small Allen key multitool and pedal spanner, as some mail order bikes will come with these and instructions, you could contact the seller to ask or wait and see if it is included.